# On odd perfects and spoofs

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, divisibility, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

This question is an offshoot of this [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205692).

Let $\sigma$ be the classical sum-of-divisors function.  An *odd* perfect number $N$ is said to be given in *Eulerian* form if $\sigma(N)=2N$ and $N={q^k}{n^2}$ where $q$ is prime with $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Descartes, Frenicle, and subsequently Sorli conjectured that $k = 1$ always holds.

If the DFS conjecture on odd perfect numbers is true, then we have:
$$q = \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)} = -1 + 2\cdot\frac{n^2}{2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)}$$
$$\frac{q+1}{2} = \frac{n^2}{2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)}.$$

It follows that
$$\sigma(n^2) = q\cdot(2n^2 - \sigma(n^2))$$
and
$$n^2 = \left(\frac{q+1}{2}\right)\cdot(2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)).$$

Does it now follow that
$$\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)) = 2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)?$$

Comment: Given $\frac{q+1}2=\frac{n^2}{2n^2-\sigma(n^2)}$, the proof should be the same as in your last question.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, @JaycobColeman!  =)

Comment: You're welcome.